# Send confirmation email when user was registered by API Magento

Tags: php, api, email, magento, magento-1.9.1

I turned on the option **System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Require Emails Confirmation** and now when users registered by usual form they get the email with required account confirmation. But now I need to do the same for users created by Magento API. I set this options:

```
$result = $proxy->customerCustomerCreate($sessionId, [
    'email' => 'mycustomemail@gmail.com',
    'firstname' => 'testfirstname',
    'lastname' => 'testlastname',
    'password' => 'testpassword',
    'website_id' => 1,
    'store_id' => 1,
    'group_id' => 4,
]);
```

When I compared records in database for user created by form and API, they were exactly the same. I mean fields **website_id** and **store_id** were the same. How can I debug this or maybe you can tell me how to implement this feature into Magento's API?

P.S: **System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts** is set to **Global**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is to override Model Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php.
More about that [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/overriding_an_existing_api_class_with_additional_functionality) !

Answer (score 0):

The following may be useful. when using the Soap to register clients, the modified email is sent as follows.

```
\ app \ code \ core \ Mage \ Customer \ Model \ Customer / Api.php
```

Line 64 will find

```
public function create($customerData)
{
    $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData);
    try {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setData($customerData)
                    ->save();
```

Place the following often.

```
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail("registered","",1);
```

This will send the mail.